# Using variable inside curl

Tags: php, curl, onesignal

I'm using web api for multiple mobile applications. I used PHP for my api. Every mobile app using different onesignal account. On react native side, i'm sending rest API key with axios. And on the api side, im wanna try this api key inside curl.

I traditional dot concatenate inside curl. But when mobile app use api, it returns empty error.

```
$api_key = 'ASDFGHJKLSI';

$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                                   'Authorization: Basic ."$api_key".'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

Is it right way to use variable inside curl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have there problem with quotes. Use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic ' . $api_key));
```